# Tailwind item placement

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind css to create this page. But I cant get the heading over the table and the button under the table. Can anyone please help me?

I have attached the image of what it looks like and where I want to place the heading and the button.

[image: Preview]

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-center">
  <P class="font-bold flex flex-initial">Sms Template:</P>
  <div class="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center">

    <div class="firstbox border border-black">
      <div class="mx-11 my-10 px-10">
        <p class="py-2 text-lg font-semibold">Message For:</p>
        <select class="firstbox_select text-center" name="message" id="message">
          <option selected disabled>Invoice</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="mx-11 my-20 px-10">
        <P class="py-4 text-lg font-semibold">Available parameters</P>
        <table class="table auto text-center">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4">Client Full name</td>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4">[fullname]</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4">Invoice ID</td>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4">[invoice_id]</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4">Invoice Date</td>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4">[invoice_date]</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4">....</td>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4">....</td>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="w-full py-3 mt-6 font-medium tracking-widest text-white uppercase bg-gray-700 shadow-lg focus:bg-gray-600">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need first to change the first `flex-row` to `flex-col` to align as column instead of a row. Then eventually, you can remove `min-h-screen` in the child, since it will push the title at the top and the button bellow the screen. Here's the illustration: https://play.tailwindcss.com/9km3y1Jkr2

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in one of the comments, you need to switch `flex-row` to `flex-col` at the top level `div` to apply the style of `flex-direction: column`.

Basically,

- left to right: `flex`
- top to bottom: `flex flex-col`

You can also just use `flex` instead of specifying `flex flex-row` whenever you want row alignment. It seems like you might know this already since in the second `div` you just specify `flex`.

Aside from the question, I notice that you have some custom classes in your HTML. If you're not using tailwind via CDN you should attempt to add the additional styling to the `tailwind.config.js` file so that all of your styling is in the markup.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
  <P class="font-bold flex flex-initial">Sms Template:</P>
  <div class="flex items-center justify-center">

    <div class="firstbox border border-black">
      <div class="mx-11 my-10 px-10">
        <p class="py-2 text-lg font-semibold">Message For:</p>
        <select class="firstbox_select text-center" name="message" id="message">
          <option selected disabled>Invoice</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="mx-11 my-20 px-10">
        <P class="py-4 text-lg font-semibold">Available parameters</P>
        <table class="table auto text-center">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4">Client Full name</td>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4">[fullname]</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4">Invoice ID</td>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4">[invoice_id]</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4">Invoice Date</td>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4">[invoice_date]</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4">....</td>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4">....</td>
              <td class="border border-black tb px-4"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="w-full py-3 mt-6 font-medium tracking-widest text-white uppercase bg-gray-700 shadow-lg focus:bg-gray-600">
  </div>
</div>
```